# not able to store the output of grep in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
PROJECT_KEY=$(grep sonar.projectKey /home/karthik/sonar-project.properties | awk -F '=' '{print $$2}');
```

The output of the grep is not getting stored in the variable `PROJECT_KEY`

Comment: Have a look at the [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#The-shell-Function).

Comment: Make variable references have the form `$(NAME)`.  You are assigning `PROJECT_KEY` to the make variable named, literally, `grep sonar.projectKey /home/karthik/sonar-project.properties | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'`.  Unsurprisingly, that variable does not exist and so you get back the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You need the shell function to call grep:

```
PROJECT_KEY=$(shell grep sonar.projectKey /home/karthik/sonar-project.properties | awk -F '=' '{print $$2}');
--------------^
```

GNU Make manual page: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#The-shell-Function